# 16GB SD-memory card became corrupt, now stuck at 512kb

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, memory-card

I've got two 16GB SD-memory cards that suddenly stopped working correctly. Windows reports that it wants to format them in order to make them functional again. However, I'm not able to make the new partition bigger than 512kB. I've also tried a couple of partition applications and they don't seem to be capable of doing a better job.

It seems that this person was in the same situation: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/4gb-sd-card-cant-reformat-stuck-at-512-kb

Is it still hope for them? Any suggestions?

Comment: What tools have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

That generally means that you've got a cheap knock-off memory card, possibly a counterfeit of a reputable brand. There's probably no hope for it, but you might try asking for a refund.

Comment: The brand is Lexar, model 16GB Premium Series 60x, bought online from a very big and serious vendor. Worked without problems for a year.

Comment: Was it Expansys?  They have fake items creep into their inventory from time to time.